# Toolkits/Libraries for CSS in ASP.NET (like the Ruby library 'Less' )

Tags: asp.net, css

So, I just saw the Ruby library 'Less'. And I want that functionality...

Are there any existing libraries for ASP.NET which will give me the same sort of functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt at playing around with [Less for .NET](http://www.dotlesscss.com).

Answer (score 0):

Less just happens to be written in Ruby, it doesn't require that you be developing a Ruby [on Rails] application. There is no reason why you can't use it on an ASP.NET project, you just need to install Ruby and ruby-gems.

Comment: Unfortunatley I am working in a strictly Microsoft environment.  I don't have enough control over the envrionment to add ruby.  I have enough control to add a usercontrol, or class...  Unfortunately.

Comment: Ah yes, the problem with a lot of .NET shops - if it ain't Microsoft, we ain't interested. Infuriates me... Ah well, guess you have to wait for some kind soul to port it ;-)

Comment: Im that kind soul whos on it :-)